# Is there a way to alter interday stock graphs on dash with python so that times after 16:00 and before 9:30 are not plotted?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to create a dashboard that shows inter-day price movement of stocks on dash in python but times after the market closes are being shown even though there is no data in between those times.

Is there a way to amend the graph to pick up at 09:30 from where it left off at 16:00?

I have tried to graph as objects:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly as plt
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import  Input, Output
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from openpyxl import Workbook

dayDates = []
endt = datetime.today()
dayDates.append(endt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
begdt = endt + timedelta(days=-3)
dayDates.append(begdt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
trbegdt = endt + timedelta(days=-365)
dayDates.append(trbegdt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Pulls minute by minute stock prices from short term variable to today
yfdfmin = yf.download("^DJI", start=begdt, end=endt, interval="1m")['Adj Close']
yfdfmin.index = yfdfmin.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

app = dash.Dash()
colors = {
    'background': '#fcfcfc',
    'text': '#353844'
}

app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='Dow',
            figure={
            'data': [
                go.Scatter(x=list(yfdfmin.index),
                    y=list(yfdfmin['^DJI']),
                    # visible=False,
                    name="Close",
                    showlegend=False)
            ]
        }
    ),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own problem that in retrospect is quite simple. I simply deleted the x-axis from my graph so that only the values were plotted. Hope this simple solution can help others.